# Notepad++ Replace function

Tags: replace, notepad++, notepad

Can somehow automatically replace with this outcome:

**INITIAL:**

```
"eye","doc":441,"engagement":35877,"impression":1987869,"reach":294757,"repost":441}}
```

**OUTCOME:**

```
{"emojiAnnotations":{"eye","doc":441,"engagement":35877,"impression":1987869,"reach":294757,"repost":441}}
```

When "eye" and so on are variables....(only titles are the same)??

I thought to use - something like - "*","doc" replace (as an expression) with {"emojiAnnotations":"*","doc", but this will not keep variable "eye" and so on.

**P.S.** This is part of replacement process so to add at the beginning is not acceptable

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52074490/edit) and add more context. more lines before and after and expected result.

Comment: @Toto where eye and numbers- this area will change, just imagine that on the top and bottom random different information. This is a big JSON file. But I need to figure out with this section (if this is not possible... then sad()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this OK for you?

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `"[^"]+","doc"`
- Replace with: `{"emojiAnnotations":{$0`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
"[^"]+"     : 1 or more not quote beweeen quotes
,"doc"      : literally
```

**Replacement:**

```
{"emojiAnnotations":{   : literally
$0                      : the whole match
```

**Result for given example:**

```
{"emojiAnnotations":{"eye","doc":441,"engagement":35877,"impression":1987869,"reach":294757,"repost":441}}
```

Comment: By any chance, do you know how to do it in python??

Comment: @NANA: It's pretty similar. Try this: `res = re.sub(r'("[^"]+","doc")', '{"emojiAnnotations":{\g<1>', str)` you have to `import re` before.